# How to add vue plugins to Vite?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9

when i was using webpack instead of vite i used to write this code in app.js

```
// for File uploads
import vueFilePond from "vue-filepond";
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
// image preview in file pond
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css";

import FilePondPluginFilePoster from "filepond-plugin-file-poster";
import "filepond-plugin-file-poster/dist/filepond-plugin-file-poster.css";

// file size validations
import FilePondPluginFileValidateSize from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size";
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type";

const FilePond = vueFilePond(
    FilePondPluginImagePreview,
    FilePondPluginFilePoster,
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
    FilePondPluginFileValidateType
);
```

but now with Vite this is not working.
i tried adding

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/css/app.css',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
         vueFilePond                        *****************************this************

    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '$': 'jQuery',
        },
    },

});
```

this is not working. Please help!

Comment: You need to provide more context. What error is showing? Consider to create a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i got the solution. sorry i forgot to update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked for me!

```
// for File uploads
import vueFilePond from "vue-filepond";
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
// image preview in file pond
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css";

import FilePondPluginFilePoster from "filepond-plugin-file-poster";
import "filepond-plugin-file-poster/dist/filepond-plugin-file-poster.css";

// file size validations
import FilePondPluginFileValidateSize from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size";
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type";

const FilePond = vueFilePond(
    FilePondPluginImagePreview,
    FilePondPluginFilePoster,
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
    FilePondPluginFileValidateType
);
```

Vue.use(AnyComponent) ; THis was not working in my case

So i tried adding component in below code. this worked for me.

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            **.mixin({ components: { FilePond } })**
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```